# Name of the sound settings application in Ubuntu?

Tags: sound, kubuntu, xubuntu

I'm trying out Xubuntu and Kubuntu. I have a complicated sound setup which I knew how to setup in Ubuntu but I'm having trouble doing the same in Xubuntu and Kubuntu. I'd like to install the main GUI application from Ubuntu (the one where you click on a taskbar and go to preferences and you see all the devices, input, output...) to try to set the sound in Xubuntu and Kubuntu. What is the name of package I need to install?
Should I expect and conflicts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 11.04

It's very straightforward in 11.04...

however note from comments received - Xubuntu made an active decision not to include the gnome-packages since they depend very much on gnome settings, indicators, etc. Xubuntu and Xfce use xfce4-miser. When it is not sufficient, xubuntu advise pavucontrol be added instead.

The name of the package in ubuntu is `gnome-media`

From a quick test in xubuntu - if you install this, it will replace the screen displayed when you choose sound-preferences from the panel.

The command launched in `gnome-volume-control`

In terms of packages installed -

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-media
```

gave the following results:

```
The following extra packages will be installed:
  gnome-media-common libgladeui-1-11 libgnome-media0
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gnome-media gnome-media-common libgladeui-1-11 libgnome-media0
```

## 11.10

Its not so straightforward in 11.10...

The package in oneiric is called `gnome-control-center` and you would display the sound preferences with the command

`gnome-control-center sound`

If you try to install (simulated) you will notice it will effectively try to install most of the Unity shell...

```
sudo apt-get -s install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: gnome-volume-control: command not found

Comment: I tested this in xubuntu 11.04 - what version of xubuntu are you using?

Comment: I tried on Xubuntu 11.10 and Kubuntu 11.10

Comment: ... updated the answer

Comment: Yes, that doesn't sound good. I'll have to stick to what I have. Thank you.

Comment: gnome-volume-control and gnome-media are not the packages in Xubuntu. Xubuntu made an active decision not to include those since they depend very much on gnome settings, indicators, etc. Xubuntu and Xfce use xfce4-miser. When it is not sufficient, we advise pavucontrol be added by the user.

Comment: Charlie-tca - in 11.10 xubuntu? They dont exist in ubuntu 11.10. I agree with xubuntu devs not to use gnome packages - the OP in his question however was asking whether it was possible - yes its possible in 11.04 - not easily possible in 11.10... why the down-vote?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's the same as what you get from the top bar in Ubuntu, but `pavucontrol` might help.

Answer (score 1):

in ubuntu 18.04 try alsamixer it has a text-based interface with vertical bars you can adjust for speakers, headphones etc, using the arrow keys;
alsamixer can be installed like this:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-utils
```

start by typing at the commandline (terminal)

```
alsamixer
```

exit by pressing ESC